# Looking for a canonical reference: everyone who attains jhana will be a god of that realm in the next life

Tags: reference-request, rebirth, jhana, god

Looking for a canonical reference: that everyone who attains jhana will be a god of that realm in the next life.

I'm fairly sure I've seen that claimed in scholarship, either Buddhist or otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is about common interpretations of [AN 4.123](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.123.than.html).

Comment: anything in the current adhidamma?